# Device pixels and screen.width

Tags: html, css

The [doc.](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) says the `screen.width` contains dimensions measured in device pixels - that is the pixels that never change because they are feature of the monitor.

1. If i'm right that "device pixels" is just physical pixels that's specified as "Screen Resolution" in manual?
2. If so (question #1) why do i get different values when i change the "Screen Resolution" in Windows? Shouldn't it be always 1920 if my monitor is specified as 1920x1080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen.width` is the width of the device screen, at the set resolution. Your monitor is specified as 1920x1080 because that's the number of physical pixels it has (2,073,600), and thus the maximum resolution it can display.

However, you can still down-scale the resolution so that each physical pixel shows more than one "CSS pixel". That's what happens when you change the Screen Resolution in windows. Think of it like a "zoom".

Comment: "each physical pixel shows more than one "CSS pixel"" - shouldn't be rather "one CSS pixel is composed of more then one physical pixel"???

Comment: @Mulligan81, I believe both sentences are essentially the same. "*To get one whole CSS pixel, you need X physical pixels*" or "*with X physical pixels you can get one whole CSS pixel*".

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc you referenced, the answer for #1 is "no". I guess, the point is, browser only knows what resolution of the screen is set by OS, and doesn't know what physical resolution the display actually has.